# How to get JButton below the JTextFields

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

I have created a GridLayout for my GUI to show 6 rows and 4 columns. I am trying to get the two buttons I have "Calculate" and "Exit" to show in the 6th row. I only have two pane.add of four for row 5 (which is the weight label and textfield). I'm just trying to get the calculate and exit buttons to be on their own row. I tried to do pane.add(); to fill the gap and couldn't get it to work. What am I missing so that I can get the buttons on their own row?

basically I have

```
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 4)); 

    pane.add(score1L);
    pane.add(score1TF);
    pane.add(weight1L);
    pane.add(weight1TF);
    pane.add(score2L);
    pane.add(score2TF);
    pane.add(weight2L);
    pane.add(weight2TF);
    pane.add(score3L);
    pane.add(score3TF);
    pane.add(weight3L);
    pane.add(weight3TF);
    pane.add(score4L);
    pane.add(score4TF);
    pane.add(weight4L);
    pane.add(weight4TF);

    pane.add(weightAvgL);
    pane.add(weightAvgTF);

    pane.add(calculateB);
    pane.add(exitB);
```

Comment: I was able to use pane.add("");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible options:

- Add empty JLabels to fill in any gaps.
- Use mixed layouts -- nest JPanels, each using its own layout and add components to them. For example, the overall JPanel could use BorderLayout. The textfields/labels could be in a GridLayout or GridBagLayout using JPanel added BorderLayout.CENTER to the main JPanel. The JButtons could be held in their own GridLayout using JPanel that is then added BorderLayout.PAGE_END to the main JPanel.
- Use a layout manager that allows for more complex layouts such as a GridBagLayout, or better perhaps, a 3rd party layout manager such as MigLayout.
- Perhaps the best of all --use a JTable to hold your data grid, add it to a JScrollPane, and then place your buttons below the JScrollPane.